# What traffic interchange does this picture show?

Tags: driving, identify-this, photography

I found [this attractive picture](https://s33007.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Future-of-Transport-1024x768.jpg)

[image: http://cowen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Future-of-Transport.jpg]

from http://www.cowen.com/reports/exploring-the-future-of-transportation/ and wondered what interchange it's based on.

It's perfectly symmetrical so the creator likely mirrored it along the median or central reservation.

Also, is the lighting real? The shadows suggest that it was taken at night, but the blue lights seem unreal (if not just oversaturated).

Comment: it's probably mirrored around the center of the road on top. Note that the curved ramps that dive under it do not continue on the opposite side.

Comment: The blue/yellow difference if probably due to some sections of the roads being lit with sodium lamps and others with white light. Then the white balance of the entire photo has been tweaked to make the sodium yellows whiter and the whites bluish.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's not mirrored at all, since the symmetry is rotational.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, bad word choice on my part.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it wasn't your choice of words in the first instance since it was in the question; I pinged you only to include you in the conversation because you adopted it.

Comment: **Shoop da woop!** That is a *major* photoshop job. Aside from the more desirable half of the interchange being cloned, he also shooped out some buildings.  I assume the attractive lighting is totally faked.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This seems to be an interchange just outside Bangkok, at [13°38'51.3"N 100°41'01.9"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place//@13.6481162,100.6852269,16z?hl=en&gl=us).

[image: Intersection of Bang Na - Chon Buri Expy and Kanchanaphisek Expy, Thailand]

It looks like the photograph must have been flipped along one of its axes in addition to the rotational symmetry introduced by duplicating and flipping the area south of Bang Na - Chon Buri Expy (the major toll road bisecting the interchange).

**Edit:** Thanks Giorgio for reminding me to link the source for the photograph in the question by Anucha Sirivisansuwan, captioned [Road traffic in city at thailand.](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/road-traffic-city-thailand-542888290?src=o-4pqRcK9UH4Es_YZtLgZw-1-3)

Comment: Amazing. Out of interest, how did you find this?

Comment: @HenningMakholm mostly luck! Reverse image search found me the photographer's Shutterstock page, and they were based in Thailand. So I looked at a couple dozen different major highway interchanges around Bangkok in Google's satellite view, searching for that characteristic circle-park-thing in one of the loops.

Comment: It's not clear that he photographed the original aerial drone shot; this on [Dreamstime stock photo](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-highway-junction-aerial-view-bangna-east-bangkok-taken-august-image76684017) calls it *Highway junction in Bangna, the east of Bangkok from aerial view. Taken in August 2016.*

Comment: @Giorgio I doubt that's the same source photo; the greenery in the south-eastern loop isn't there.